# What is Thomas explaining about the boroughs?

Tags: extremely-loud-and-incredibly-close

In Extremely Loud and Incredibly Close, Thomas is explaining something about the 6th borough. I can't recollect too well but is also explaining something about people pulling the central park? What is this conversation about, what is he trying to tell his son here?

Answer (score 1):

I read in this place - [Extremely Loud & Incredibly Close.](http://www.thisisbarry.com/#!In-Review-Extremely-Loud-and-Incredibly-Close-2011-Explained/ce4s/5690a3a40cf2f5ee60f55040)

Tom Hanks tells his son about fake story that once upon a time there was 6 boroughs in NY and not only 5. 6th borough floated away. The people floated away too. Central park was in 6th borough and it was floating away also. Then Manhattan people use hooks and pull central park to stop it from floating away with 6th borough. It is a fake story he tells his son.

Why because (from link):

> Thomas tells this to his son because he wants to ensure his extremely
>   science oriented son is not devoid of an imagination. Unlike other
>   kids Oskar is a little too drawn to science and accepts only things
>   that are backed by scientific facts. Thomas perhaps feels that Oskar
>   should have an element of faith in things that may or may not be
>   proven scientifically. This is not necessarily religious. Humans don’t
>   really understand the way of life and how everything works. Science
>   merely helps us understand things that are repeatable in nature.
>   Thomas perhaps feels an over dependence on science and its limited
>   explanation of the cosmos could make Oskar pessimistic in life. This
>   is why Thomas asks him are you an optimist or a pessimist. Oskar
>   responds saying he’s an optimist.